# INSERT SELECT TOP (n) ORDER BY column not included in the destination table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is that possible to insert from select when the select statement has more columns that the table to insert to ?

consider scenario:

```
INSERT INTO table_1             --table_1 consist only of one column 

SELECT  TOP 10  col1, col2      --col_2 is only selected because is used in ORDER BY
FROM            table_2
ORDER BY        col2 DESC
```

The above statement will result with error. One way I would accomplish that is to use sub-query like that

```
INSERT INTO table_1 

SELECT  TOP 10  col1
FROM    (
        SELECT      col1, col2
        FROM        table_2
        ORDER BY    col2 DESC
    ) AS t
```

But I'm wondering if there is a straight forward way for example using equal operator like in `UPDATE` statement.

**UPDATE**

I apologize for submitting oversimplified example. That was because I've took it for granted this will apply to my scenario without actually testing it.

This is the reproduced context of my query (tested on sqlfiddle as have no SQL Server installed on my home PC)

```
CREATE TABLE table_1 (id INT)
CREATE TABLE table_2 (id INT, col2 INT)
CREATE TABLE table_3 (id INT, col2 INT)
INSERT INTO table_2 VALUES (1,3),(2,2),(3,1)
INSERT INTO table_3 VALUES (1,3),(1,2),(3,1)

INSERT INTO table_1

SELECT  TOP 1  t.id, t.Qty
FROM table_2
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT table_2.id, COUNT(table_3.id) AS Qty
FROM table_2
INNER JOIN table_3 on table_3.id = table_2.id
GROUP BY table_2.id 
) AS t ON (t.id = table_2.id)

ORDER BY t.Qty
```

The original query is much more complex, therefore I would like to avoid another sub-query if this is possible.

This query results with the error saying:

```
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.: INSERT INTO table_1 SELECT TOP 1 table_1.id FROM table_1 INNER JOIN ( SELECT table_2.id, COUNT(table_3.id) AS Qty FROM table_2 INNER JOIN table_3 on table_3.id = table_2.id GROUP BY table_2.id ) AS t ON (t.id = table_1.id) ORDER BY t.Qty
```

Comment: You can order by `col2` without the need to actually select it.

Comment: @GhostGambler how could I do that ? I've tried but resulted with error saying that the order by column has to be included in the select statement.

Comment: Is your query really as simple as the example, or is it more complex?  If you have any subqueries involved, then it is true you cannot order by on the parent query on a column not selected in the subquery.

Comment: @mellamokb It's much more complex therefore I'm looking for straight forward solution

Comment: @Dimt: The problem is that your current example isn't capturing enough complexity about your real problem, because doing an order by without select works fine on your simple example.

Comment: In other words, you have a `GROUP BY` or `UNION`. You need to include that fact in your question. In that situation, your second solution is probably the simplest way of handling your problem, unless you want to use a CTE (which is what I would do).

Comment: It might be the problem which outis nihil says, I will review my query an try to put better example of what I'm doing

Comment: Could you comment on down-votes please

Answer (score 2):

Up don't need to include the order by col in the select list.

```
CREATE TABLE table_1 (id INT)
GO
CREATE TABLE table_2 (col1 INT, col2 INT)
GO
INSERT INTO table_2 VALUES (1,3),(2,2),(3,1)
GO
INSERT INTO table_1             --table_1 consist only of one column 
SELECT TOP 2 col1
  FROM table_2
 ORDER BY col2 DESC
```

Comment: This is exactly what I've tried, but debugger was showing that the col2 has to be included in the select.

Comment: That script works for me in SSMS against a 2012 DB. Pretty sure it'll work against any other version. Does my sample work for you? If so then we need details on your specific error and, as suggested in the question comments, you may have oversimplified for the question.

Comment: Yes, now I know I did oversimplified the question :) will provide correct context.

Comment: I see the update. That helps. You can share the SQLFiddle link as well. Now, you are inserting into a 2 column table_3, with the 1 column result set. That's what there errors says. What do you want in table_3 id and i columns?

Comment: Well, I need to know some total values on order them descending for each id in `table_2` which are stored in `table_3` before inserting to `table_1` which actually is a temp table. The id's from `table_2` are conditionally selected on values which do not exist in `table_3`. I hope it make sense

Comment: So table_1.id should be t.id and table_1.i should be t.Qty?  And to the records already exist in table_1? It looks like you are maybe mixing up inserts and updates.

Comment: Yes, I've mixed that up trying to format the code (I must be tired), however the case persist. I will come back to question when I fresh :). Thanks for your time, appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying the column that you are trying to insert into?

```
INSERT INTO table_1 (id)
SELECT  TOP 1   table_1.id
FROM            table_1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT      table_2.id, COUNT(table_3.id) AS Qty
    FROM        table_2
    INNER JOIN  table_3 on table_3.id = table_2.id
    GROUP BY    table_2.id 
) AS t ON (t.id = table_1.id)
ORDER BY t.Qty
```